# chat app: it freezes when creating a new socket

Tags: java

I have created a short java chat app. 3 classes: the GUI, the server and the client.

The gui has its own getters so that they are talked to by the objects of the other classes.

When I try to create the socket, it first popped me up the Firewall saying that it had blocked an app from trying to open a port in my computer, alright, I clicked on "allow app" and I further even expressly put it on the list of allowed apps of Firewall. The problem now is that when I click on the Menu to create the socket, it Freezes the app completely and you can't do anything but abort it.

The app, of course,is based on Threads, and every time I wanto to create a socket such as when I click on the menu item

```
if(ae.getSource() == servertalkstogui.getCreate()){
```

it then starts a Thread that is run at its Run method. But at that point it freezes. I dont know if I am on an infinite loop or what. Also, I dont like using a "sleep" in a Loop, but so far I dont know any other alternative, but the most important thing is to detect the bug that freezes the App

```
package backend;

import frontend.Gui;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Alvarito
 */
public class Server implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    private ServerSocket ss;
    private Socket s;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;
    private Gui servertalkstogui;

    public Server(Gui in) {
        servertalkstogui = in;

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getSource() == servertalkstogui.getCreate()) {
            servertalkstogui.getAreachat().append("hola");
            System.out.println("creado");
            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.run();
        }

        if (ae.getSource() == servertalkstogui.getButton()) {
            String linea = servertalkstogui.getTextField().getText();
            writeLine(linea);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            ss = new ServerSocket(9999);
            s = ss.accept();
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                this.closeServer();

            }
            catch (IOException ex) {

                System.out.println("se jodio");
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            e.getLocalizedMessage();

        }

    }

    public void writeLine(String linea) {

        try {
            oos.writeObject(linea);
            servertalkstogui.getAreachat().append(linea);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }

    }

    public void readLine() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Object aux = ois.readObject();
                if (aux != null && aux instanceof String) {
                    servertalkstogui.getAreachat().append((String) aux);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {

        }

    }

    public void closeServer() throws IOException {

        try {
            oos.close();
            s.close();
            ss.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.addSuppressed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the Client class

```
package backend;

import frontend.Gui;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Alvarito
 */
public class Client implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    private Socket s;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;
    private Gui clienttalkstogui;

    public Client(Gui in) {

        clienttalkstogui = in;

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == clienttalkstogui.getConnect()) {

            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.run();
            clienttalkstogui.getAreachat().append("me he conectado");
            System.out.println("hola");
        }
    }

    public void writeLine(String linea) {

        try {
            oos.writeObject(linea);
            clienttalkstogui.getAreachat().append(linea);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }

    }

    public void readLine() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Object aux = ois.readObject();
                if (aux != null && aux instanceof String) {
                    clienttalkstogui.getAreachat().append((String) aux);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            s.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the Gui class:

```
package frontend;

import backend.Client;
import backend.Server;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Alvarito
 */
public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private JMenuBar bar;
    private JMenu menu;
    private JMenuItem connect, create, exit;

    private JTextArea areachat;
    private JTextField campochat;
    private JButton botonchat;
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    /* WE CREATE INSTANTIATED OBJECTS OF CLASSES INTERACTING WITH THE GUI */
    Server servidor = new Server(this);
    Client cliente = new Client(this);

    /* CREATING THE CONSTRUCTOR */

    public Gui() {

        super("CHAT WINDOW");
        this.setSize(400, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /* INSTANTIATE THE OBJECTS */
        bar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        connect = new JMenuItem("Conectar");
        create = new JMenuItem("Crear");
        exit = new JMenuItem("Salir");

        areachat = new JTextArea();
        campochat = new JTextField(20);
        botonchat = new JButton("Send");
        scroll = new JScrollPane(areachat);

        /* THE BAR IS PLACED IN THE JFRAME WINDOW */
        this.setJMenuBar(bar);
        /* THE MENU IS ADDED TO THE BAR */
        bar.add(menu);

        /* THE ITEMS ARE ADDED TO THE MENU */
        menu.add(connect);
        menu.add(create);
        menu.add(exit);

        /* MAKE ITEMS LISTEN TO THE EVENT FROM THE CODE CLASSES */
        create.addActionListener(servidor);
        connect.addActionListener(cliente);

        exit.addActionListener(servidor);
        exit.addActionListener(cliente);

        botonchat.addActionListener(cliente);
        botonchat.addActionListener(servidor);

        /* CREATING THE LAYOUTS */
        /* AREACHAT */
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;

        this.add(scroll, gbc);

        /* TEXTFIELD */

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        this.add(campochat, gbc);

        /* BOTON */

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;

        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;

        this.add(botonchat, gbc);

        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    /* CREATING THE GETTERS AND SETTERS */

    /* GETTERS */
    public JTextArea getAreachat() {

        return areachat;
    }

    public JMenuItem getCreate() {

        return create;
    }

    public JMenuItem getConnect() {

        return connect;

    }

    public JTextField getTextField() {

        return campochat;
    }

    public JButton getButton() {

        return botonchat;

    }

    /* SETTERS */

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Gui objeto = new Gui();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to familiarize yourself with the debugger.  Or add some logging so you can see what's going on inside your program.

Comment: yes, it is true, but I have no idea how to use the debugger and it is difficult to develop without using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use start() instead of run() in order to start a thread.

Calling run() just call the run method, without starting a thread. And you then block in the ui thread

Comment: oh  my! I cant believe I was making that mistake. ! Thank you.